# How much time per day do I need to spend studying?

Tags: learning-methods

Usually, I have trouble with time management with learning a new language from time to time. For example, I have the feeling I am spending too little or too much time, which makes a bad habit of constantly changing the time.

As shown by studies, not opinions, how much time do I need to spend learning a new language on average per day?

Comment: Not a scientific proof, but I found the bite-sized lessons of Duolingo very useful. One per day has helped me get up to speed with French.

Comment: If time is an issue, it's generally better to study for a small amount of time (10-15 minutes) every day consistently than to miss days and try to make up for it later.

Comment: This question is unanswerable. First clue: It contains the word "should." This is a "primarily-opinion based" question indicator. Can you make it more objective?  Second, you don't tell us your goals. Some people "should" study their language 18 hours per day to achieve their goals. Others "should" study 5 minutes per week to achieve their goals. This question needs to be made much more specific, and much more objective.

Comment: @Flimzy Even if I agree that this question is primarily opinion based, I do not think that the word "Should" is a sure-fire sign of it. [link](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/16462/does-should-imply-an-unquestionable-command?rq=1)

Comment: @Bougret: I didn't say it was a sure-fire sign of it. I said it was an indicator. The word "should" is used to express a degree of obligation or expectation. In most questions we're likely to see here, it will be obligation; and obligations in the realm of language learning is based on opinion or personal circumstance. If it's used in the context of expectation, that's different... "If I study 8 hours per day, should my Spanish improve?"

Comment: @Flimzy, I agree to your point. It is true that we are most likely to get opinion based questions with "Should" here. And the obligation meaning will probably be used exceptionally. For expectation, well, its a different topic.

Comment: Editing to remove the word "should," but not change the meaning of the question, is a case of addressing the symptom, without addressing the cause. The problem here wasn't the word "should" *per se*. It's what the word should *indicates* about the problem: That you're seeking an opinion (or situation-specific, if you prefer) answer. Try editing the question to be more objective.

Comment: You don't say in the question to what (expertise) level you are trying to reach over what period of time. This detail needs to be added to the question or it is anyone's guess.

Comment: Expanding on the comment from @user3169 with examples: an Erasmus student should study half a day every day, while a hobby learner would be fine with studying 4-5 hours per week.